# Why does a single unwind segue have varying behavior?

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, uistoryboard, unwind-segue

I have a Swift app containing a storyboard with three different view controllers. A user can transition through these view controllers in two different ways:

VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3

OR

VC1 -> VC3

From VC3, users can press a "back" button, which programmatically unwinds to VC1 with the following code:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UnwindToVC1", sender: self)
```

That unwind segue is associated with an Unwind Segue created in the storyboard, which unwinds to the following function in VC1:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwind")
}
```

If a user goes directly from VC1 to VC3, the app correctly unwinds, returning the user to VC1 and printing "Unwind".

However, if a user goes from VC1 to VC2 to VC3, the unwind still returns the user to VC1, but the unwindToVC1 function is never called and "Unwind" is never printed.

Why would the same unwind segue behave inconsistently? Is there a way to ensure that the unwind function in VC1 is always called?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your result.  My test prints "Unwind" in both cases.  I tried both modal segues and show(push).

Comment: Where do you put the `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UnwindToVC1", sender: self)` code?

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for trying! Yeah, it's very weird. I'm just using modal segues.

Comment: @jms There is an IBAction function that is tied to the "touch up inside" event of a button in VC3. The function does some validation of data input by the user, and if everything looks ok, it calls the unwind segue.